# Objects are not valid as a React child - how to fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

Trying to implement some react code to connect to a Websocket.

```
  var WebSocket = React.createClass({
    displayName : "WebSocket",
    ws : new WebSocket('wss://5.196.65.55:8443'),
    render: function() {
      return (
        React.DOM.div(null,
          this.ws,
        )
      );
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object WebSocket]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `WebSocket`.

Self explaining but I cannot understand how to fix it. Any help? (React learner here :-))
NOTE: using react 15

Comment: Any reason for not learning the latest `React`?

Comment: Try to render reactFragment instead of null i.e.
React.DOM.div(</>,
          this.ws,
        )

Comment: I'm partially working on an already existing implementation with version 15 so I am keeping it for starting. Then will migrate to 16

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb obviously it gives me an error on the < char. I am not using JSX at this time